# Query for data categorisation in specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

```
| client_id | product_type |
|-----------|--------------|
| c_1       | toy          |
| c_2       | toy          |
| c_3       | furniture    |
| c_3       | furniture    |
| c_3       | book         |
| c_4       | toy          |
| c_4       | furniture    |
| c_5       | book         |
| c_5       | book         |
| c_5       | book         |
```

As you can see, each client can have multiple products assigned.

I have to categorise each client by products they have.

- If clients have product `toy` assigned to them, they should have `toys`
  in the result table, no matter if they have other products.
- If clients have product `furniture` assigned to them, they should have `furnitures` in the result table, no matter if they have other products.
- If clients have product `book` assigned to them, they should have `books` in the result table, no matter if they have other products and so on...

Each client must appear in the results only once.

For the above example the result will be:

```
| client_id | cat        |
|-----------|------------|
| c_1       | toys       |
| c_2       | toys       |
| c_3       | furnitures |
| c_4       | toys       |
| c_5       | books      |
```

Comment: Are `client_id` and `product_id` really varchar? Or are they int?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Each one states that a customer can only appear once, however, you don't explain what happens when they do. From your result set, looks like you want the `MIN` product. Have you *tried* to solve this problem yourself? If not, why not? If yes, share your attempt please.

Comment: You say `and so on...` you need to define a priority for every category, which would be best assigned in a table, not magically in a case statement.

Comment: Do you have a look up for the plural value for the singleton i.e. `'Toy'` and `'Toys'`? Not every plural, in English, is a case of adding an s to the end. For example furniture can be singular or multiple items (a piece of furniture, pieces of furniture). Furnitures isn't really right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE to assign the priority, e.g.

```
select client_id, 
  'cat_' + 
     min(case product_type 
        when 'toy' then '1'
        when 'furniture' then '2'
        when 'book' then '3'
      end)
from tab
group by client_id
```

Would be easier if you have a table defining the category/priority for each product, then it's a simple join instead of CASE.

Comment: This is basically the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic to get the results you want is:

```
select client_id, 
       (case when sum(case when product_type = 'toy' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'toys'
             when sum(case when product_type = 'furniture' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'furnitures'
             when sum(case when product_type = 'book' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'books'
        end) as category 
from t
group by client_id;
```